# Error when attempting to clone a Git repository

Tags: git, windows-xp

When attempting to clone a repository via an https (and subsequently an http) connection using Git 1.9.5 on a WinXP machine, I noticed the following error message appear:

> The procedure entry point BIO_clear_flags could not be located in the
>   dynamic link library libeay32.dll.

Being a completely new user of Git, I am unsure as to how to proceed.

Comment: That looks like a Windows issue, not a git issue.

Comment: I was concerned that git might have an additional dependency that I was unaware of. OpenSSL perhaps?

Comment: Have you checked this question? http://superuser.com/questions/746063/github-for-windows-7-missing-libeay32-dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, `libeay32.dll` is used to create a secure connection to the server. That said, you can probably try one of these:

- Try making the http request instead of https. i.e instead of command:

  ```
  $git clone https://github.com/....
  ```

  you can try:

  ```
  $git clone http://github.com/...
  ```
- Your dll may be corrupt. You can try downloading a copy from internet, and copy it to your systems folder (dont forget to backup your existing dll file).

Hope it helps.. :)

Comment: Thanks Tarun and @nwinkler. I installed OpenSSL-Win32 and as part of its installation process, it placed a copy of libeay32.dll into the C:\Windows\System32 folder. (after I deleted the old copy that was already present in that folder).  The problem was immediately resolved.